# Is there a UK English dictionary for the Swype keyboard?

Tags: swype

I've just signed up for [Swype beta](http://beta.swype.com/) but there's no option I can see for an UK English keyboard, which means I get incorrect :¬) spellings for 'colour', 'neighbour', 'favourite' etc.

Anyone know if there's a custom UK dictionary available or some other workaround?

**Edit:**
I've just bulk added 320 UK spellings compiled from the [Ubuntu English translation guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EnglishTranslation/WordSubstitution).
I put the list of words in a text file, opened and selected all and hit the skype button to add them to the dictionary.
This works pretty well and remembers my preference for words like 'vapour' (which has the same stroke as 'vapor').

Comment: There's a [non-English forum](http://forum.swype.com/forumdisplay.php?59-Non-English-Languages), but I don't see a solution to UK English. Have you tried adding your specific words using Word Addition? There's a video on that in their Tips & Tricks [section](http://swypeinc.com/tips-tricks.html).

Comment: I've tried adding a few obvious words that way but there are quite a lot in total:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences

Comment: Have just added over 80 words in one go using the method suggested by psiko here: http://androidforums.com/htc-droid-eris/57645-swype-can-you-edit-dictionary-easily.html#post2034521

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is now](http://www.androidcentral.com/swype-android-keyboard-updated-number-improvements).

Answer (score 5):

Using the version of Swype that comes pre-loaded on a UK Galaxy S, I can long-press on the "Q" in the top-left of the keyboard to get a list of languages pop-up. The top two options here on my phone are "UK English" and "US English".

If I switch between the two, and then swype through "colo[u]r" (obviously you have to swype across the "u" to get from the "o" to the "r") I get "color" as the result in US English, and "colour" as the result when set to UK English, so it would seem that there are two separate dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks GAThrawn. I only see the option for 'US English' when I do that (plus French, Spanish, German, Italian, Portuguese  and Japanese). Good to know there is a UK dictionary out there somewhere though.

Comment: @pelms Just had a further look and according to a few forum posts like this one http://androidforums.com/android-applications/233981-swype-uk-english.html UK English was in previous Swype versions but isn't in the newer versions for some reason, my Galaxy has v2.4.44.10814 and does have UK ENglish, which fits with that.

Comment: @pelms It might be good to contact the Swype people and ask if they have a UK beta version, and tell them to make one if not ;)

Answer (score 3):

Recent versions of Swype (I have 3.26.92.38303) allow you to download additional languages:

Select `Settings` → `Language & inuput` → `Swype` → `Language Options` → `Manage Languages` → `Download languages` and choose the language that you wish to add.